# How to listen UDP Packets without send request to Server use GCDAsyncUdpSocket in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, udp, gcdasyncudpsocket

I want to make an application that is able to listen on the specific port without send any request to Server. That means, another app will broadcast data every 10s and my app needs to listen that broadcast without send any request to that other app. I tried use the example Echo server code in **GCDAsyncUdpSocket** lib to test but the Echo server app cannot receive any data. Is there any way to do that?